# Configuration Issues for Log Collection and Sending in rSyslog Linux

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I am trying to send logs to an NLB endpoint from Syslog on a Linux server using local0, local1, etc. variables and pointing to etl folders that I have on the same server. I am having trouble with the syntax and would appreciate some help. Below is an example with fake data of how I have it configured

```
# Logs for the ETLS and send them to OpenSearch
local0.*                                -/path/to/etl/1/*.log
local1.*                                -/path/to/etl/2/*.log
local2.*                                -/path/to/etl/3/*.log

local0.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
local1.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
local2.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

This is not working for me, but if I use the following link:

```
*.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

Like that

```
# Logs for the ETLS and send them to OpenSearch
local0.*                                -/path/to/etl/1/*.log
local1.*                                -/path/to/etl/2/*.log
local2.*                                -/path/to/etl/3/*.log

*.* @@url-nlb-aws.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:6000;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

It collects all the data but from the entire rSyslog configuration file, except the local variable.

Does anyone know how to send custom variables or multiple custom paths? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: This is an external configuration file where all .conf files ("/etc/rsyslog.d/") are located and are taken into account in the rsyslog master file "/etc/rsyslog.conf".